# Modulos duplicados en ckeditor para angular 4?

Tags: angular, plugin, ckeditor

Estoy intentando añadir un plugin de ckeditor a un inline-editor.

Cuando ejecuto me aparece el siguiente error: "Some CKEditor 5 modules are duplicated" Y un enlace donde me dice que tengo que hacer para solucionarlo https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules

La solución que obtengo en la web la he replicado en mi código y aún asi me sigue saliendo el mismo error."Some CKEditor 5 modules are duplicated"

Adjunto mi código:

**TS**

```
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';
import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';
import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';
import Italic from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic';


ngOnInit(): void {
    ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        plugins: [ Essentials, Paragraph, Bold, Italic ],
        toolbar: [ 'bold', 'italic' ]
    } )
    .then( editor => {
        console.log( 'Editor was initialized', editor );
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error.stack );
    } );
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="editor"></div>
```

Anteriormente lo tenía con de la manera mas optima con angular, pero como al añadir los plugins me aparecía el mismo error, opte por dejarlo igual que el enlace.

**Mi código anterior**

**HTML**

```
<ckeditor (focus)="focusCkEditor()" (blur)="blurCkEditor()" class="matCkEditor top" matCkeditor
                        formControlName="cuerpo1" [editor]="Editor" [config]="config"></ckeditor>
```

**TS**

```
 import * as InlineEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-inline';
 this.config = {
   plugins: [  ], //Al intentar añadir un plugin me salta error de duplicados
   toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', '|', 'undo', 'redo'],

   language: 'es'
 };
```

Entiendo que con '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-inline' no se puedan añdir plugins por la duplicidad de modulos.

Lo que no llego a entender, es que dejandolo tal cual esta en la solución de CkEditor me siga saltando el mismo error.

Mucahs gracias.

Comment: Eliminaste los paquetes y los volviste a instalar como lo recomienda el link ?

Comment: Hola! @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO No lo había hecho, lo hice y me dio el mismo error. Lo conseguí solucionar por otro método. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He conseguido añadir el plugin como necesitaba. No es la forma que intento plantear en la pregunta, pero igualmente me ha servido.

Lo que hice fue descargarme un build:

```
git clone -b stable https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-inline.git
cd ckeditor5-build-classic
npm install
```

y en ella añadir los plugins que yo necesitaba.

```
npm install --save-dev @ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment
```

Se añade en src/ckeditor.js los imports necesarios y buildeas esa carpeta con `yarn run build`

Al final, es lo mismo que pone en la documentación de la librería: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/installing-plugins.html#adding-a-plugin-to-a-build

Una vez en el código es seguir los mismos que tenía desde un principio, pero el import del editor ahora será donde este tu build personalizado.

**TS**

```
import * as  InlineEditor from '../../../../assets/ckeditor5-build-inline';
export class AppDialogMailComponent implements OnInit {
  public editor = InlineEditor;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ckeditor class="matCkEditor top" matCkeditor [editor]="editor"></ckeditor>
```